# How can I destroy overlap between 2 objects Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, collision, phaser-framework, overlap

I am working on a game, where I add overlap between 2 objects, but after a certain action between them I want to destroy the overlap. I can't  figured it out. Any help is appreciated.

`Update function`

```
 function checkOverlap(postava, rozcestnik) {
            var boundsA = postava.getBounds();
            var boundsB = rozcestnik.getBounds();
            return Phaser.Geom.Intersects.RectangleToRectangle(boundsA, boundsB);
        }


        if(this.keys.E.isDown && checkOverlap(this.postava, this.rozcestnik) == true)
        {

         this.colliderRozcestnik = this.physics.add.overlap(this.postava, this.rozcestnik, diaOknoRozcestnik.bind(this), null, this)

         this.physics.world.removeCollider(this.colliderRozcestnik);
         
        }


        function diaOknoRozcestnik(postava, rozcestnik)
        {
        postava.anims.play("left");
        this.gzDialog.visible;
        this.gzDialog.setText("I need to find some car mechanic to repair the engine.");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean _...destroy the overlap..._? You want to remove the overlay listener? or Destroy the overlapping object?

Comment: Remove the overlap listener, sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: did my answer solve.your question, or dors something not add up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would just need to call the `removeCollider` in the function `diaOknoRozcestnik`.

```
function diaOknoRozcestnik(){
    this.physics.world.removeCollider(this.colliderRozcestnik);
    //...
}
```

Or you could write a small wrapper like this:

```
...
if(this.keys.E.isDown && checkOverlap(this.postava, this.rozcestnik) == true){
  this.colliderRozcestnik = this.physics.add.overlap( this.postava, this.rozcestnik,
    (...args) => {
      this.physics.world.removeCollider(this.colliderRozcestnik);
      diaOknoRozcestnik.call(this, ...args);
    });
}
...
```

> ***Btw.:** if you are using `bind` or `call` with `this` as the first parameter, you don't need to pass the `this` reference to the `overlap` function, and so you could also omit the `null`, shortening the whole call, as seen in the example above.*

**Like this:**

```
this.colliderRozcestnik = this.physics.add.overlap(this.postava, this.rozcestnik, diaOknoRozcestnik.bind(this));
```